# This release will not be available to any users because you haven't specified any testers for it yet

Tags: android, google-play

I was trying to upload my application to Google play and got this warning in the image attached:
[image]

I searched for this error, never found a previous thread, I only got this link:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

and it's talking about making internal test or open closed test.

I am also wounding, can I skip this, but it says "will not be available to any users..." I just want to know this just for the record not because I am willing to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, I can skip the testing and go directly to the release, take a look on this link: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

If we need to make a version first for testers we can use google play but if our application has already passed the testing phase(if owner's testers already approved the application) we can go directly to step 2 which is called "Create a Release".

If you haven't passed the testing phase yet, you can just use the testing phase as described in the provided link above.